# What do the function arguments in django settings mean?

Tags: python, django

Django newbie here. I'm on Django 2.1 and was taking tutorials when I saw this line in the settings.py file. What exactly does this line mean? What does os.path.join do?

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While we're all be happy to help you with real programming issue, you're still supposed to search by yourself before asking. Googling for "python os.path.join" would have sent you straight to the relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join()` joins parts of path to a complete, system independant, path.

On different operating systems you have different conventions of paths, for example Windows vs Linux.

`os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` just joins `BASE_DIR` which is path to your base Django directory and `static`, resulting in something like `path/to/django/static`.